# Delegated type vs. json column in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a situation when inherited types in DB have a completely different set of properties and almost none in common. For example, we have a table Item and we want to store different types there.

```
Item < ApplicationRecord

LiquidItem < Item
# properties: volume, size

PhysicalItem < Item
# properties: weight, unit
```

Later there is a plan to add more and more items. The database is PostgreSQL. I was thinking to use [delegated types](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/DelegatedType.html) from rails, but there I'm not sure. According to the examples, inherited types usually share some data with the parent. In my situation, they have many different properties. Does it make sense to use delegated types? or would it be better to serialize each type to json and save it in a json column. Any advice?

Comment: Whatever you do don't use `serialize`. Its an old hack for storing JSON/YAML in text/varchar columns - if you use it with a native JSON/JSONB type you'll actually be storing a string instead of objects/arrays. You don't actually have to do anything - the driver will do it for you.

Comment: As for the use of JSON - thats really a matter of trade-offs. Using a JSON column is a form of denormalization and will increase the complexity of queries - plus you're dealing with primitive data types supported by JSON instead of the data types supported by Postgres. One example of a promblem related to this is that JSON only has a single number type. Dealing with primitive types also invites garbage code compared to encapsuling the data in higher level constructs such as associations and models.

Comment: The pro of a JSON column is that you have fewer joins and its vastly superior to other approaches for schemaless data like the EAV anti-pattern. If this is a greenfield project and this is a core of the domain model you might want to consider a document based store instead of a relational database.